# Grouped bar charts, in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've seen other javascript charting libraries that supported grouped barcharts, of the sort in the image below. I've not seen this as an explicit option in chart.js's online editor.

Is it possible to do grouped bar charts of this sort in chart.js? Is it easy? Is there a template for it in their online editor?

[image]

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Yes, you can provide multiple data sets using the `datasets` property, which is an array of containing groupings of values. Each data set contains a series of values in `data` that correspond to the `labels`.

See two slightly different examples below depending on your version of Chart.js.

---

#### Chart.js v1.x

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = {
    labels: ["Chocolate", "Vanilla", "Strawberry"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Blue",
            fillColor: "blue",
            data: [3,7,4]
        },
        {
            label: "Red",
            fillColor: "red",
            data: [4,3,5]
        },
        {
            label: "Green",
            fillColor: "green",
            data: [7,2,6]
        }
    ]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, { barValueSpacing: 20 });
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/11of5ysf/).

---

#### Chart.js v2.x

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = {
    labels: ["Chocolate", "Vanilla", "Strawberry"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Blue",
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            data: [3,7,4]
        },
        {
            label: "Red",
            backgroundColor: "red",
            data: [4,3,5]
        },
        {
            label: "Green",
            backgroundColor: "green",
            data: [7,2,6]
        }
    ]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        barValueSpacing: 20,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3g07d09/).

Comment: The syntax in the last line throws an error: Bar is not a function; I am using Chart.min.js 2.2.1.

Comment: @TobiG. I added a Chart.js v2.x example.

Comment: @Jacub Budin Chart.js v2.x example doesn't render correctly. For Vanilla there is no green bar.

Comment: @Shahid That's because the Y-axis minimum value was `2`—such is Chart.js's default behavior to take the smallest value—not `0` as you expected. I've updated the example to make it more clear, but it was rendering correctly.

Comment: I'm wondering how did you find this information. I couldn't find on the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, @JacobBudin. Kindly help me with one more thing. If I want to show the respective value inside each bar then what? And if I switch the graph to horizontalBar graph then do I need to make any change except for changing the type? Thanks again..

Comment: @JacobBudin Hi. How can I fix the distance between the blue, red and green bars? In my case when there is more data the bar comes close and if the data is for say only 1 then the bars are very far apart. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Good day,Everytime i execute my code, red color is incomplete, i mean no blue in the second data, but in my code i supply it very well? same in the third data. missing something

Answer (score 1):

Yes,it is possible to do grouped bar charts of this sort in chart.js and so easy

**Step by Step:-**

***Step1:-***

First of all add the script link of charts.js:-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

***Step2:-***

Add div in body of html'

```
 <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> 
          <div id="chart_div"  style="width: 800px; height: 300px;">
          </div> 
         </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

***Step3:-***

```
<script>
var densityCanvas = document.getElementById("densityChart");


var Data1 = {
 label: 'A',
  data: [3.7, 8.9, 9.8, 3.7, 23.1, 9.0, 8.7, 11.0],
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(99, 132, 0, 0.6)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(99, 132, 0, 1)',
  yAxisID: "y-axis-gravity"
}
var Data2 = {
 label: 'B',
  data: [3.7, 8.9, 9.8, 3.7, 23.1, 9.0, 8.7, 11.0],
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(99, 132, 0, 0.6)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(99, 132, 0, 1)',
  //yAxisID: "y-axis-gravity"
}
var Data3 = {
 label: 'C',
  data: [3.7, 8.9, 9.8, 3.7, 23.1, 9.0, 8.7, 11.0],
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(99, 132, 0, 0.6)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(99, 132, 0, 1)',
  //yAxisID: "y-axis-gravity"
}
```

***Note-***:You can make multiple Var data which you want to display and only give the yAxisID to one var Data which then display as one group yaxis

```
var planetData = {
  labels: ["A", "B", "C"],
  datasets: [Data1,Data2, Data3 ]
};
 
var chartOptions = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      barPercentage: 1,
      categoryPercentage: 0.4
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      id: "y-axis-Registered"
    } 
    ]
    }
};
 
var barChart = new Chart(densityCanvas, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: planetData,
  options: chartOptions
});
</script>
```

***Note:-***
When I am trying to use this offline Chart.js library and create chart for my case then this pretty solution helps me a lot :-

In picture Last Look:-
[In picture Last Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br9CI.png)