# Chart.js Bar Chart: How to remove space between the bars in v2.3?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to remove the space between my bar chart bars, but even though I see this solution many places it doesn't work for me.  It's also not mentioned in the Chart.js docs so that is odd.  Can someone tell me how to specify it?

```
var options = {
    barValueSpacing : 1,        // doesn't work; find another way
    barDatasetSpacing : 1,      // doesn't work; find another way

    legend: {
        display: false          // Hides annoying dataset label
    },
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem) {
                return tooltipItem.yLabel;
            }
        }
    }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvasX").getContext("2d");          
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Answer (score 73):

You need to set `barPercentage` and `categoryPercentage` to `1.0` on the x-axis scale. Add this to your `options` object:

```
var options = {
    ...
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            categoryPercentage: 1.0,
            barPercentage: 1.0
        }]
    }
};
```

See http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options

Comment: Minor fix required: `scales` should be an object, not an array.

Comment: A few others have noted this is now-hidden answers, but this does **not** appear to work for the horizontal bar chart. I'm currently looking for a workaround and will post if I find anything.

Comment: @TopherFangiofor me this actually worked for horizontal bar chart (type: "horizontalBar",) !!!!!

Comment: actually what worked is setting those values, in his Hill's answer, but for yAxes.

Comment: Be sure you don't have the Dataset barThickness value set, or it will override the barPercentage setting.

Comment: @PhilipF, you have a point well marked because I have the situation in which I need both barThickness and bar spacing, for a vertical grouped bar chart (v2.9.4), and these settings results exclude each other.

Comment: If you need to remove the space between bars but keep the space between groups like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180871/grouped-bar-charts-in-chart-js only set the `barPercentage`  and leave the `categoryPercentage` to default

Answer (score 14):

In version 3.2.0 set `barPercentage` and `categoryPercentage` to 1.0 within each data set:

```
var datasets = [
  {
    ...
    barPercentage: 1.0,
    categoryPercentage: 1.0
  }
]
```

See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.2.0/charts/bar.html for more details

Answer (score 8):

Both `barpercentage` and `categorypercentage` are property of `dataset` option in chart.js. You can see them in the list [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-properties) and its default value.

```js
    const labels = ["AA","BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF"];
    const data = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            categoryPercentage: 0.8, // notice here 
            barPercentage: 0.8,  // notice here 

            label: 'Male',
            data: [-189, -97, -2076, -691, -7887, -3687],
            //...
        }]
    };
```

However, according to the [configuration document](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/#dataset-configuration),

> The dataset options can be changed at multiple different levels.

Just like the example below. the option can be used in global configuration level.

```js
    const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {

            categoryPercentage: 1.0, // here 
            barPercentage: 0.98,  // here

            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    stacked: true
                },
            }
        },
    };
```

If you are interested in how the two property interacts, please see the detail [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barpercentage-vs-categorypercentage).