# CharJS 2.5.0 - How to remove space between bars

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I created this fiddle. It contains a ChartJS bar chart:

https://jsfiddle.net/07pzys9t/

```
        var options = {
        legend: { display: false },
        animation: {
            animateScale: true
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                barPercentage: 1,
                categoryPercentage: 1,
                barThickness : 45
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                barPercentage: 1,
                categoryPercentage: 1,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        },
        tooltips: {

        }
    };
   var dataForChart = {
        datasets: [{
            data: [0.2, 0.4, .78, 0.05],
            backgroundColor:["#FF6384","#4BC0C0","#FFCE56","#36A2EB"],
            borderWidth: 0
        }],
        labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    };
    var chart = new Chart($("#statsRenderingResultsDeliveryClaimsChart"), {
        type: 'bar',
        data: dataForChart,
        options: options
    });
```

How can I remove the space between the bars? I read this answer:

[Chart.js Bar Chart: How to remove space between the bars in v2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879445/chart-js-bar-chart-how-to-remove-space-between-the-bars-in-v2-3#answer-40411121)

But it doesn't seem to work because if you look at the code in the fiddle I created I add the `barPercentage` and `categoryPercentage` properties on both axes.

Any idea on how to achieve the wanted behaviour?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

If you use chart with responsive aspect, you don't be force a width value to your bars.

You just need set your xAxes with this two attributes

```
xAxes: [{
    barPercentage: 1.0,
    categoryPercentage: 1.0
}]
```

Instead of :

```
xAxes: [{
    barPercentage: 1,
    categoryPercentage: 1,
    barThickness : 45
}]
```

You need use percent value with responsive aspect using barPercentage and categoryPercentage attributes.