# Artefacts when showing compact vertical bar chart in chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I have a vertical bar chart which is displaying exactly as I want it when the number of bars is up to 50 or so.  However, I also need to display up to 365 bars, one for each day of the year.  It displays the bars with the code I was using but there were artefacts due to using a barPercentage less than 1.0 and a border.

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1.0)',
borderWidth: 2,
categoryPercentage: 1.0,
barPercentage: 0.8
```

So when the number of bars is over 100, I change these values as follows and do a chart update:

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1.0)',  // No transparency in the bar colour
borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1.0)',
borderWidth: 0,
categoryPercentage: 1.0,
barPercentage: 1.0
```

However, there is still a faint visible vertical line between the bars where I would expect nothing.  I'm on Mac OSX with Safari and I also see the problem on iPad and iPhone.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong??
(click on the 'SWITCH' button to swap between 50 and 120 bars)

https://jsfiddle.net/8xdLb9qe/

Answer (score 1):

I've searched and found this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879445/chart-js-bar-chart-how-to-remove-space-between-the-bars-in-v2-3#comment111730526_40411121):

> Be sure you don't have the Dataset barThickness value set, or it will
> override the barPercentage setting. [Philip F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1758120/philip-f)

I change the chart settings as follows:

```
myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('thisChart'), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
    labels: myScales,
    datasets: [{
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1.0)',
        data: myValues,
        barThickness: 16 // 
    }]
    },
    options: option
});
```

Here is the [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/xr01vqu7/).

---

Full code:

```js
var thisChart = null;
var myScales = [];
var myValues = [];
var numBars = 50;

var option = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  interaction: {
    intersect: false,
    mode: 'nearest'
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      display: true,
      grid: {
        drawOnChartArea: false,
        drawTicks: false
      }
    },
    y: {
      max: 100,
      grace: '5%',
      grid: {
        drawTicks: false
      },
      display: true
    }
  },
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    hover: {
      mode: null
    }
  }
};

myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('thisChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: myScales,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1.0)',
      //borderWidth: 2,
      data: myValues,
      barThickness: 16,
      //categoryPercentage: 1.0,
      //barPercentage: 0.1
    }]
  },
  options: option
});

for (var i = 1; i != numBars; i++) {
  myScales[i] = i;
  myValues[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50 + 1) + 50);
}
displayGraph();


function displayGraph() {

  // Remove the old data
  myChart.data.labels.pop();
  myChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data.pop();
  });
  myChart.update();

  // Add in the new data
  myChart.data.labels = myScales;
  myChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => {
    dataset.data = myValues;
  });

  if (myValues.length > 100) {
    myChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => {
      dataset.barPercentage = 1.0; // Remove gap between bars
      dataset.borderWidth = 0; // Remove bar border
      dataset.backgroundColor = 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1.0)'; // Remove transparency
    });
  } else {
    myChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => {
      dataset.barPercentage = 0.8; // Default width of gap between bars
      dataset.borderWidth = 2; // Default bar border
      dataset.backgroundColor = 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)'; // Default bar background colour
      dataset.borderColor = 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1.0)'; // Default bar border colour
    });
  }
  myChart.update();
}

function switchBars() {

  if (numBars == 50) { // Toggle number of bars
    numBars = 120;
  } else {
    numBars = 50;
  }

  myScales.length = numBars;
  myValues.length = numBars;
  for (var i = 1; i != numBars; i++) {
    myScales[i] = i;
    myValues[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50 + 1) + 50);
  }

  displayGraph();
}
```

```css
.chart-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60vh;
  margin-top: 4em;
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-right: 2em;
}

.styleSelectorButton {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="thisChart"></canvas>
</div>

<div id="selectorButton" class="styleSelectorButton">
  <input type="button" onclick="switchBars()" class="button" value="SWITCH">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this.

Comment: Firstly, I don't use 'barThickness' and, as the answer to your comment notes, the docs suggest setting barPercentage and categoryPercentage to 1.0.
By setting 'barThickness' to a high value, the definition of the graph is lost...
I think it might be worth posting this question on the chart.js GitHub site.

Comment: @Andrewatthebeach you should post this question there, indeed. Once posted, please, add the link of the post(s) in your question.