# Barchart reducing space between bars

Tags: html, chart.js

I am trying to reduce the space between bars, and I am pretty sure it has to be within this piece of code. I removed the code that displays the legend and yAxes assuming I would not need to edit those parts.

[image: A bar chart showing liquid level but with spaces between the data points]

```
barchart = new Chart(myChart, {
                type:'bar',
                data:{
                    labels: {{ data.x_vals | tojson }},
                    datasets:[{
                        label:'Liquid Level',
                        data:{{ data.y_vals }},
                        backgroundColor: gradient,
                        borderWidth:1, //Effects plotted line on chart
                        borderColor:'white',
                        hoverBorderWidth:1,
                        hoverBorderColor:'#000',
                        barPercentage: 1.0,
                        categoryPercentage: 1.0
                    }]
                },
                options:{
                     // legend is here
                    },
                    scales: {
                    // yAxes is here
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        autoSkip: true,
                        padding: 4,
                        fontSize: 12
                    }
                }]
            },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js Bar Chart: How to remove space between the bars in v2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879445/chart-js-bar-chart-how-to-remove-space-between-the-bars-in-v2-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the category and bar percentages to 1:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      categoryPercentage: 1,
      barPercentage: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

Make sure you have at least chart.js version 2.9 installed since any version below its not implemented yet

Comment: I tried doing that but the spacing doesn't disappear. I also tried making the values less than 1.0, following this site https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barpercentage-vs-categorypercentage

Comment: If you have a version below 2.9 it wont work since it wasnt implemented yet, also that documentation you linked is for v3 while you are using v2 so you might want to use the documentation for your specific version: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/ replace last number with your version you are using

Comment: I didn't realize the library that was imported was outdated, the code itself was from last year. Thank you so much! I updated the library and it now works