# Chart.js multiple datasets

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I am having a problem with my chart.js with multiple datasets. I have four(4) datasets. The problem is the data keeps separating.

The data sets are: rekorida, merchandizing, tradecheck and others those data sets should be in one date. How can I merge the four datasets into 1 date?

Here is the json result

0: {Rekorida: 2, Date: "January 2019"}
1: {Merchandizing: 1, Date: "January 2019"}
2: {TradeCheck: 1, Date: "January 2019"}
3: {Others: 1, Date: "January 2019"}

Screenshot:
[image]

```
    var dates = [];
    var rekorida = [];
    var merchandizing = [];
    var tradecheck = [];
    var others = [];

    for (var i in data){
         dates.push(data[i].Date);
         rekorida.push(data[i].Rekorida);
         merchandizing.push(data[i].Merchandizing);
         tradecheck.push(data[i].TradeCheck);
         others.push(data[i].Others);
    }

    var rekoridaData = {
         label: 'Rekorida',
         data: rekorida,
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 99, 132, 0.6)',
         borderWidth: 0,
         yAxisID: "y-axis-1"
    };

    var merchandizingData = {
         label: 'Merchandizing',
         data: merchandizing,
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(99, 132, 0, 0.6)',
         borderWidth: 0,
         yAxisID: "y-axis-1"
    };

    var tradecheckData = {
         label: 'Trade Check',
         data: tradecheck,
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(99, 132, 0, 0.6)',
         borderWidth: 0,
         yAxisID: "y-axis-1"
     };

     var othersData = {
         label: 'Others',
         data: others,
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(99, 132, 0, 0.6)',
         borderWidth: 0,
          yAxisID: "y-axis-1"
      };

      var dateData = {
         labels: dates,
         datasets: [rekoridaData, merchandizingData, tradecheckData, othersData]
      };

      var chartOptions = {
          scales: {
             xAxes: [{
                 barPercentage: 1,
                 categoryPercentage: 0.6
             }],
             yAxes: [{
                  id: "y-axis-1"
             }]
           }
       };

       var ctx = document.getElementById("activities-chart").getContext('2d');
       Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Montserrat';
       Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 10;
       var chart = new Chart(ctx,{
            type: charttype,
            data: dateData,
            options: chartOptions
         });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouped bar charts, in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180871/grouped-bar-charts-in-chart-js)

Comment: Can you try to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180871/grouped-bar-charts-in-chart-js if this answers your problem.