# How to create a bar chart like this using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to create this chart using chart.js and I got the data in a json file. the problem is to how to create this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jLis.png

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28181877/12634779) answer your question?

Comment: Most welcome, just a small tip: try to describe your answer (in words) as much as possible so you get more attention, for example replacing "like this" with "grouped bar chart" will boost the question!
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide is a good point to start from. Cheers