How to group the Y and X axis labels at the very bottom left corner in Chart.js?
I'm using Chart.js v4.4.3.
My goal is to group the Y and X axis label to achieve something like this:

I wasn't able to find what options to use to group this two axes labels together in https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html.
Would this be possible to achieve with the Chart.js options? Am I missing something?
This is what I have so far in my options, but it's not quite what I'm trying to achieve.
{
  scales: {
    x: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Day',
        align: 'start',
      },
    },
    y: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Min',
        align: 'start',
      },
    },
  }
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180871/grouped-bar-charts-in-chart-js tried this? anyway didnt get the grouping the y axis part

unfortunately, not exactly what I'm trying to achieve :(

There is little room to configure axis titles, you have already linked to
the page in the documentation that lists the available options.
There are a few approaches possible to achieve what you have described, none as simple as setting an option.
The solution that seems to me the most direct and adaptable is to draw the mixed label yourself on the canvas, using a custom plugin.
The implementation below uses the beforeUpdate
callback to get all the options for the plugin and to adjust the padding so the label fits the canvas and afterDraw to actually render the label each time it is required.
The code in the snippet can be simplified by hard-coding some of the options, or, on the contrary, it can be extended to
include other options, like multiple axes, other corners than bottom-left, etc.


//import {toFontString} from 'chart.js/helpers'; // in a module environment
const toFontString = Chart.helpers.toFontString; // with umd script

const plugin_mix_title = {
    id: 'mix_title',
    beforeUpdate(chart){
        let text = chart.options.plugins.mix_title.text;
        if(!text){
            const xTitle = chart.options.scales.x.title.text,
                xTitleDisplay = chart.options.scales.x.title.display,
                yTitle = chart.options.scales.y.title.text,
                yTitleDisplay = chart.options.scales.y.title.display;
            if(xTitle && yTitle && !xTitleDisplay && !yTitleDisplay){
                text = `${yTitle} / ${xTitle}`;
            }
        }
        if(text){
            const ctx = chart.ctx;
            const font = Object.assign({}, Chart.defaults.font,
                    chart.options.plugins.mix_title.font ?? {}),
                textColor = chart.options.plugins.mix_title.color ?? Chart.defaults.color;
            const fontString = toFontString(font);
            const margin_y = chart.options.scales.x.ticks.padding +
                    chart.options.scales.x.grid.tickLength,
                margin_x = chart.options.scales.y.ticks.padding +
                    chart.options.scales.y.grid.tickLength;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.font = fontString;
            const fm = ctx.measureText(text);
            ctx.restore();
            chart.options.layout.padding.left = Math.max(
                chart.options.layout.padding.left, Math.ceil(fm.width - margin_x));
            this._preComputed = {
                text, fontString, textColor, margin_x, margin_y
            }
        }
    },
    afterDraw(chart){
        const options = this._preComputed;
        if(options){
            const {text, fontString, textColor, margin_x, margin_y} = options;
            const ctx = chart.ctx;
            const x = chart.scales.y.right - margin_x,
                y = chart.scales.x.top + margin_y;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.font = fontString;
            ctx.textAlign = "right";
            ctx.textBaseline = "hanging";
            ctx.fillStyle = textColor;
            ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
            ctx.restore();
        }
    }
};

Chart.defaults.color = 'white';
const config =  {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['05', '10', '15'],
        datasets: Array.from({length: 5}, (_, i)=>({
            label: 'D'+(i+1),
            data: Array.from({length: 3}, ()=>5+Math.floor(Math.random()*20)),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(195, 192, 255, 0.7)',
        }))
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    padding: 10
                },
                title: {
                    //display: true,
                    text: 'Day',
                    //align: 'start',
                },
            },
            y: {
                title: {
                    //display: true,
                    text: 'Min',
                    //align: 'start',
                },
            }
        },
        categoryPercentage: 1,
        plugins:{
            legend:{
                display: false
            },
            mix_title: { // available options
                // font: Chart.defaults.font, // all items: size, family, style, lineHeight, weight
                color: "lightblue"//Chart.defaults.color,
                // text: null // if null (default), synthesize y.title/x.title
            }
        }
    },
    plugins:[plugin_mix_title]
};
new Chart('myChart', config);
<div style="height: 200px">
    <canvas id="myChart" style="background-color:rgb(0,0,48)">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>



